# Prove statement of Predicate calculus

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I have to prove a statement $$\forall x\exists y\left ( \Phi \left ( x \right )\vee \Psi \left ( y \right ) \right ) \vdash \exists y\forall x  \left ( \Phi \left ( x \right )\vee \Psi \left ( y \right ) \right )$$ (the variable $y$ has no occurrences in formulas $\Phi \left ( x \right )$, $\Psi \left ( x \right )$).

Using rules of calculus, i got this one  $$\left ( \Phi \left ( y \right )\vee \Psi \left ( y \right ) \right ) \vdash \left ( \Phi \left ( x \right )\vee \Psi \left ( x \right ) \right )$$

But this is not all isn't it?

I think, that I have to use the fact about $y$ here, but I don't how..

I have to do a formal proof, using this rules
[image: I have to do a formal proof, using this rules]

Comment: How do you need to prove it?  Doing a formal proof?  If so, what inference rules do you have?

Comment: In general I don't think that's correct. If $x$ is drawn from the empty set, then the formula on the left is vacuously true, but the right hand side may not be true e.g. if $y$ is also drawn from the empty set.

Comment: @Bram28 Yes, formal proof. I added ruels.

Comment: @ColmBandal sometimes this statemaent is not correct, but it must work with the condition on the variable, which we have

Comment: Anyone see how to derive $\dfrac{ \emptyset }{A \vdash A}$ ?  Seems like a pretty big omission.  Unless they mean the $\vdash$ in the correct sense, in which case they mean $\dfrac{X}{Y}$ in the incorrect sense.

Comment: @DanielV $A\vdash A$ is an axiom

Comment: @justastudent Colm Bhandal's statement has nothing to do with whether the $y$ occurs free in $\Phi$ or $\Psi$. The point was that $\forall x.P$ is *always* true when the domain is empty no matter what $P$ is, and $\exists x.P$ is *always* false when the domain is empty no matter what $P$ is. I don't believe the rules you've given imply that the domain is non-empty. If I'm not mistaken, then you won't be able to prove a statement that would be false if the domain was empty using them.

Comment: It's not common in math, but with just predicate logic sometimes the domain of discourse is assumed to be nonempty.